# propagate change of scrollbar range to text box in dat.gui

Tags: javascript, dat.gui

Just wondering if somebody else had the same problem.
I created a scroller inside a gui in dat.gui.
When I later want to change the min and max values of the scroller, I do:

```
scrollBar.__min=0;
scrollBar.__max=listNbBaseElements[newValue2]-1;
scrollBar.initialValue=0;
scrollBar.object.scrollProgress=0;
```

Unfortunately, the change does not seem to propagate to the text input box created by dat.gui on the right side of the scroller. The min and max input of the text input stays the same as the original values initially defined in the scroller creation. When I try to update the content of the input, it does not accept values in the new range...
How can I find the input box __min and __max properties?

Cheers!